# How can i make my python3 code do many "if input" operations at once

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x, input, artificial-intelligence

I tried make an AI just to see if i could, i couldn't. but i want it to at least work. 
Here's my code:

```
while True:
   if input(":") == "hello":
       print("Hello.")
   if input(":") == "good bye":
       print("Bye!")
   if input(":") == "how are you":
       print("Good, i don't feel much. You know, I'm an AI.")
```

if you run it you see that it does not what an AI would do.

Comment: You are now asking an input every time. Instead, try executing `input(":")` once and storing the result in a variable, then writing your `if`s against that variable. Also, what is the point of  `if True:`?

Comment: Sorry typo in my code, i actualy ment while True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `while` loop so that your code continues to execute so long as the user does not input "good bye", like so. I also input an `else` statement in case the user inputs something your AI can't handle.

```
user_input = ""
while user_input != "good bye":
   user_input = input(":")
   if user_input == "hello":
       print("Hello.")
   elif user_input == "how are you":
       print("Good, i don't feel much. You know, I'm an AI.")
   else :
      print("Say something I understand")
print("Bye!")
```

Let me know if this isn't exactly what you want or if there is something you don't understand.